# Spring MVC 3 content negotiation restrict to actions which support it

Tags: security, spring-mvc, content-negotiation

I have configured content negotiation in my Spring MVC 3 app as follows:

```
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
            <property name="order" value="0" />
            <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
            <property name="defaultContentType">
                    <ref bean="htmlMediaType" />
            </property>
            <property name="mediaTypes">
                    <map>
                            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                    </map>
            </property>
            <property name="defaultViews">
                    <list>
                            <bean
                                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                                    <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
                            </bean>
                            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                                    <property name="marshaller">
                                            <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller" />
                                    </property>
                            </bean>
                    </list>
            </property>
            <property name="viewResolvers">
                    <ref bean="tilesViewResolver" />
            </property>
    </bean>
```

This works very well -- all my views will render as html views with the 'normal' view templates, or as JSON or XML dumps of the view model data depending on the 'Accept' header.

However, this seems to be a bit of a security hole to me. Some of my actions are API-style actions, and are legitimately available in HTML or JSON or XML. However, some views are intended to be HTML-only. I don't really want end-users to be able to see all the view data just by adding ".json" to the url.

Is there any way to do content negotiation in Spring MVC, but only on actions which have explicitly opted-in to it? Can I set up a controller annotation like `@RespondsTo("xml", "json")`?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a filter through DelegatingFilterProxy to block users from accessing unnecessary content types ?

Answer (score 1):

I was just facing the same problem. `produces` attribute of `@RequestMapping` helps for that. Although it's the opposite of what you asked for - kind of opt-out instead of opt-in, but I think it's what can please you.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/categories")
public class CategoriesController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/xhtml+xml")
    public String createForm(Model model)
    {
    }
}
```

`/create` - works fine by displaying JSP view
`/create.json` - 406 Error

Comment: Trying to black-list all security holes is always worse than explicitly whitelisting only safe options, but it's better than nothing, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to use Spring Security to restrict which pages can be seen based on the content-type (or whatever other method(s) you are using for content negotiation.

Comment: That might work. Please could you expand a little on how best to do that?